# Counting the number of substrings

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

I would like to ask if there is an algorithm for counting the number of discrete occurencies of a substring in a string in O(n) time.

Comment: @alex: it's a question about the *existence* of an algorithm. OK, so nothing is truly Turing-complete due to practical limits, but I'm pretty sure that an algorithm exists in C if and only if an algorithm exists in Lisp, Javascript, or any other semi-decent programming language.

Comment: @Steve Sorry, I assumed the OP wanted example code and not just an algorithm.

Comment: @alex: well, you might be right and they do want code. Maybe I'm being too literal in only considering what they actually asked for :-)

Comment: what is n in O(n)?  Do you have one substring and one string or something else?

Comment: simple linear search for for substring in the string can also be good i guess....???correct me if i m wrong....

Answer (score 10):

**[EDIT 17/11/2013: Count the *leaf* nodes.  Thanks Vinicius Pinto!]**

You can build a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) on the text in linear time.  Then, search for your substring in the suffix tree; when you find it, count the number of leaf nodes beneath the matching node.  This is O(m + k) for a substring of length m that appears k times (add an n term for building the suffix tree).  Or, you can precalculate the number of descendants for each node in the tree using a depth-first traversal -- this will give O(m) queries.

For large texts, suffix arrays are often faster than suffix trees in practice, despite searching for a single length-m string dropping from O(m) to O(m log m).  In this case, all occurrences of a particular substring will appear as a contiguous block in the suffix array, so the width of this block is the number of occurrences.

Comment: Hi, I think you meant 'count the number of *leaf* nodes', right?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [KMP Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and modify it to increment a counter instead of returning.

Another possibility is the [Rabin-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm), however this relies on hashing, so you either have to accept the possibility of false positives while keeping the complexity linear, or accept the possibility of quadratic complexity while keeping the results 100% correct.