# Modifying a Generalised Suffix Tree to hold number of times a node appears in the text string

Tags: tree, suffix-tree, suffix-array

How do I modify the procedure in [Ukkonen's paper](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1withFigs.pdf) to hold a value for number of times a word appears in the text. Are there any such implementations available that provide the string frequency as well?

The modification I want is like for a string "hehe" the frequency count for all "h","e","he" should be 2 in the tree. Rest nodes have the default value 1.

I found some libraries like [the best so far](https://geekli.st/abahgat/repos/suffixtree) and some previous questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969448/generalized-suffix-tree-java-implementation).

But none of them describes a good enough solution to my problem. Also I have to process a very large dictionary file (about a billion words). Then the algorithm needs to be really fast. And I am ready to compromize on space a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found here: [Counting the number of substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402109/counting-the-number-of-substrings)

Basically, build the suffix tree, match the substring starting from the root and count the leaf nodes below that point. That's the number of times the word appears in the text.